# Is it correct to use "versatile" in a sentence without mentioning which thing?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, predicate-adjectives

I have seen sentences like these:

1. He’s so versatile an actor.
2. She’s a versatile entertainer.
3. The potato is a versatile vegetable.

Can I use *versatile* in these ways?

4. She is so versatile.
5. She is very versatile.

That is, can I use it without mentioning an object or in which platform she is versatile? I want to mean that she can do any work perfectly, like this:

6. She’s an all rounder.

Is this a correct way to use *versatile*?

Comment: **Versatile**, like **unique**, isn't usually qualified by 'so' or 'very' but is an absolute.

Comment: None of your original sentences are grammatical. You need to either use articles or make the subjects plural. For example, "She's *a* versatile entertainer" or "Potoato*es are* versatile vegetable*s*" or "*The* potato is *a* versatile vegetable."

Comment: It can use intensifiers, no problem. But it can't be done without articles. The first 3 sentences are ungrammatical. And thee last one is very peculiar; if that's a phrase people use around you, go ahead; but I've never heard _all rounder_, with or without hyphens, with that meaning.

Comment: I have edited to remove obvious errors that would discourage or divert people from answering.

Answer (score 2):

You can use "versatile" without saying what they're versatile in, but it might be ambiguous. The reader is forced to make assumptions about what they do. If the context is already apparent, they will probably guess correctly. For instance, if the person is a famous actor, it's obvious that you mean that their acting is versatile. Potatoes are known to be food, so it's clear that this means that it can be used in a wide variety of recipes.

Comment: The term is also heard as the ability to change roles behind the scenes.

Comment: That's part of the context that would have to be apparent.